# Connecting to Kerberos secured HBase cluster from Java application

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, apache-nifi

I am trying to connect to hbase using the following code:

@Test
public void onTrigger() throws Exception {

```
    TestRunner runner = getTestRunner();
      runner.run();
```

}

private TestRunner getTestRunner() throws FileNotFoundException, InitializationException {

```
    final TestRunner runner = TestRunners.newTestRunner(PutAllHBaseAVRO.class);
    runner.setProperty(PutAllHBaseAVRO.TABLE_NAME, "myTable");
    runner.setProperty(PutAllHBaseAVRO.COLUMN_FAMILY, "cf");
    runner.setProperty(PutAllHBaseAVRO.BATCH_SIZE, "10000");

    getHBaseClientService(runner);

    runner.setProperty(PutAllHBaseAVRO.ROW_ID,"Row1");

    // runner.setProperty(PutAllHBaseAVRO.HBASE_CLIENT_SERVICE, hBaseClient);
    runner.setProperty(PutAllHBaseAVRO.ROW_FIELD_REVERSE_STATEGY, "Reverse");
    runner.setProperty(PutAllHBaseAVRO.TS_FIELD_NAME, "dateTimeValue");
    runner.setProperty(PutAllHBaseAVRO.TS_FIELD_FORMAT, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    return runner;
}
```

private HBaseMyClientService getHBaseClientService(final TestRunner runner) throws InitializationException {

```
    final HBaseMyClientService hBaseClient = new HBase_1_1_2_MyClientService();


    runner.setProperty(HBaseMyClientService.HADOOP_CONF_FILES, "../hbase-site.xml, ../core-site.xml");

    runner.addControllerService("HBaseMyClientService", hBaseClient);

    //runner.setProperty("Kerberos Principal", "myKerberosPrincipal");

    //runner.setProperty("Kerberos Keytab", "/mypath.keytab");

   // runner.setProperty(HBaseMyClientService.ZOOKEEPER_QUORUM, "hbaseClient");

   // runner.enableControllerService(hBaseClient);

    return hBaseClient;

}
```

and get an error. Can not understand why I have such a mistake:

'HBase Client Service' is invalid because HBase Client Service is required
'Hadoop Configuration Files' validated against '../hbase-site.xml, ../core-site.xml' is invalid because 'Hadoop Configuration Files' is not a supported property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TestRunner is made for a processor which you can see when you create it and say "newTestRunner(PutAllHbaseAvro.class)". When you call `runner.setProperty(name, value)`, it is trying to set that property on the processor, but your processor doesn't have the hadoop conf files property, the service has it. To set it on the service you have to make a different call `runner.setProperty(service, name, value)`.

Comment: Thanks, did as you say                                                                                             
**final HBaseMyClientService hBaseClient = new HBase_1_1_2_MyClientService();   runner.setProperty (hBaseClient, HBaseMyClientService.HADOOP_CONF_FILES, "../hbase-site.xml, ../core-site.xml");**

I now have an error:
'HBase Client Service' is invalid because HBase Client Service is required

Comment: just didn't set the property 'HBase Client Service', thanks)